# Why I get empty global SERVER array in php?

Tags: php

I share link in facebook at my social feed.
When I put link of my personal site it calls controller from my web server:

```
.../controller/method
```

There is a global array `$_SERVER` in `method`:

```
$text = json_encode($_SERVER);
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

I try to write data to file `$file`.
Why I get empty `$text`, when Facebook grap my web page? So, Facebook does not send headers http?

Comment: `$_SERVER` is an array, not an object, and even if the request had no "headers", it would still show details configured by your server's settings (e.g., Apache, nginx, etc.). If you can hit it manually, check with `var_dump($_SERVER);` and/or `var_dump(json_decode($text));` in a browser. If you get output, check your server logs; it may be you can't write to the `$file` path you're specifying with your server's user.

Comment: Do you have a valid and writable pathname in `$file`?

Comment: I checked it, file is written, but when I call this controller from social network as faceook, I get empty data

Comment: Unless you're manipulating `$_SERVER` or have some funky server configuration, it wouldn't make sense that it's only empty when the link comes from a "social network". The server creates this internally based on details both on the server (server IP, request IP), about the request (decomposition of the URL), and details of the request (headers, query string, etc.). Only the latter would be left off the request were somehow made with no request headers. Facebook shouldn't be able to manipulate this in reality; it's part of your server.